# Fintek F71869A GPIO Control

Tags: embedded-linux, gpio

I want to control the GPIO on the Jetway Atom PC JBC373F38 (http://www.jetwaycomputer.com/JBC373F38.html). I have found that the GPIO on that PC is part (GPIO3) of the super IO chip Fintek F71869A. I has make a small code to control these GPIO pin on Linux using 0x2E/0x2F ports but it does not work. May any one have working example for this problem or tell me what is my mistake in my code. This is my code:

```
#define AddrPort 0x2E
#define DataPort 0x2F

#define WriteByte(port, val)    outb(val, port)
#define ReadByte(port)          inb(port)

#define PORT_INDEX  0xC0
#define PORT_DATA   0xC1

    //Enable 
    WriteByte(AddrPort, 0x87);
    WriteByte(AddrPort, 0x87); //Must write twice to entering Extended mode

    //< Select Logic Device >
    WriteByte(AddrPort, 0x07); // Enter selecting mode
     WriteByte(DataPort, 0x06); // Select logic device 06h: GPIO


     //<Output Mode Selection> //Set GP30-37 to output Mode
    WriteByte(AddrPort, PORT_INDEX); // Select configuration register C0h
    WriteByte(DataPort, 0xFF);

    //<Output Value>
    WriteByte(AddrPort, PORT_DATA); // Select configuration register C1h
    WriteByte(DataPort, 0xFF); //Set all bits HIGH
```

Answer (score 1):

You are enabling configuration by writing the `0x87` twice, but are you disabling the configuration mode by sending `WriteByte(AddrPort, 0xAA);` when you are done.

Your AddrPort and DataPort appear incorrect as well; they should be 0x4E and 0x4F.

See Section 6 of [this documentation](http://www.fintek.com.tw/files/productfiles/F71869A_V0.19P.pdf).

It states:

> Following is a example to enable configuration and disable configuration by using debug.
>
> ```
> -o 4e 87
> -o 4e 87 (enable configuration)
> -o 4e aa (disable configuration)
> ```

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are right, I changed the AddrPort/DataPort to 0x4E/0x4F and it works well now.