# Windows 10 iot and GPIO

Tags: windows-10, iot, gpio

I have a C&T RCO-3000 computer, Intel I5 processor x64 with Windows 10 Enterprise. The computer has 4 embedded input and 4 output.
I tried to manage those GPIO with **GpioController.GetDefault()** but it returns null.

I checked on **device manager** and there is nothing about **GPIO**. Is it correct ?
Watching at **System** the reported operative system is Windows 10 Enterprise, I should have expected a reference to IoT, maybe the wrong os was installed and GPIO device is not recognized.
I searched a lot about missing drivers or something to enable but found nothing useful.

Update 1

The chip which drives the GPIO is a **Fintek F81866A**. I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670521/programming-gpio-pins-on-a-fintek-f81866a-chipset?noredirect=1) about that chip, but I need something for Windows.

Comment: Have you checked if  the driver was running well? You can also check if the ACPI table contains the device info. Please see more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/gpio-controller-requirements-checklist).

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT I checked your link but I lack the necessary background to fully understand it. I'm an application developer, not a driver developer. I searched about ACPI table but I didn't find any easy way to watch at it. It is a low level hardware topic and I need higher level tools. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please see more information in this link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/acpi-system-description-tables).